# Add customer to multiple customer group magento2.1

Tags: magento-2.1, customer, customer-group

I set group with  `eav_attribute group_id` to multi-select and set it to varchar. But it doesn't show multi select.
I want to set my customer to multiple customer groups in magento2.1

Comment: By default, this is not possible. AFAIK, this will break Magento standards as well.

Comment: @MagePsycho I know! i want to help me to change this functionality